# What is causing Python odeint to return strange results after a certain point?

Tags: python

I'm having issues with the python odeint function. I'm using extended SIR modelling to model the spread of infectious disease and using python to solve my coupled differential equations, and then plotting them. Often the graphs look perfectly normal and return sensible and accurate results for the first x values of t but then after that they blow up to infinity or otherwise create bizarre patterns that are obviously incorrect. I'm relatively new to python and new to odeint and so am struggling to find the problem. Here is my code:

```
def plotsirhd(t, S, I, R, H, D):
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(10,4))
    ax.plot(t, S, 'cornflowerblue', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Susceptible')
    ax.plot(t, I, 'r', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Infected')
    ax.plot(t, R, 'Maroon', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Hospitalised')
    ax.plot(t, H, 'darkslateblue', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Recovered')
    ax.plot(t, D, 'k', alpha=0.7, linewidth=2, label='Dead')
    ax.set_xlabel('Time (days)')
    ax.set_ylabel('Fraction of population',labelpad=14)

    ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(length=0)
    ax.grid(b=True, which='major', c='w', lw=2, ls='-')
    legend = ax.legend(borderpad=2.0)
    legend.get_frame().set_alpha(0.5)
    for spine in ('top', 'right', 'bottom', 'left'):
        ax.spines[spine].set_visible(False)
    plt.show();

    plt.show();

def diffeq3(y, t, beta3, q3, gamma=1/9, delta=1/7, aitch=1/12, p=0.05, q0=0.45, q1=1, c=2/6665, L0=46, L1=120, L=0.8):
    def q3(t, q0, q1, c):
        if H < c:
            return q0
        else:
            return ((H-c)*q1+c*q0)/H
    def beta3(t, L0, L):
        if t < L0:
            return gamma * (1.8/(1+np.exp(-0.5*(-t+L0)))+1.8)
        else:
            if L0<=t<=L1:
                return L * gamma
            else:
                if H > 3*c/4:
                    return L * gamma
                else:
                    return 1.8 * gamma
    S, I, R, H, D = y
    dSbydt = -1*beta3(t, L0, L)*S*I
    dIbydt = beta3(t, L0, L)*S*I - (p*aitch*I + gamma*(1-p)*I)
    dHbydt = p*aitch*I - (q3(t, q0, q1, c)*delta*H + (1-q3(t, q0, q1, c))*delta*H)
    dRbydt = (1-p)*gamma*I + (1-q3(t, q0, q1, c))*delta*H
    dDbydt = q3(t, q0, q1, c)*delta*H
    return dSbydt, dIbydt, dRbydt, dHbydt, dDbydt


t = np.linspace(0, 899, 900) 
y0 = S0, I0, H0, R0, D0 
gamma=1/9
delta=1/7
aitch=1/12
p=0.05
q0=0.45
q1=1
c=2/6665
L0=46
L1=120
L=0.8
ret = odeint(diffeq3, y0, t, args=(beta, q, gamma, delta, aitch, p, q0, q1, c, L0, L1, L))
S, I, H, R, D = ret.T

plotsirhd(t, S, I, R, H, D)
```

Also, if you rerun the code multiple times often you get different errors. This issue remains for slight variations of my beta function and different parameters. Is there any way to resolve this? I would like to see the output of the coupled functions for larger values of t. Thank you.

Comment: It is not necessarily a programming problem so much as a mathematical problem. Based on your problem description, perhaps you are trying to numerically solve a [stiff differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation). To make sure you understand the relevant python, can you reproduce textbook solutions in cases which are known to have nice, numerically stable, solutions?

Comment: This seems to be the most likely problem, thanks. Other, simpler ODEs resolve fine. Thanks!